LFSR to generate a PRBS31 Test Pattern: Cannot figure out how to access the 28th tap point
I am designing a simple white noise generator using four cascaded TI CD4014B 8-Stage Static Shift Registers and one TI CD4030B Quad Exclusive-Or Gate.  Since I need the PRBS31 Test Pattern, the 31st and 28th stages are the taps.  The CD4014B only provides access to the three highest bits/stages: Q6, Q7, Q8.
Cascaded Shift Registers showing output buffers:
[-,-,-,-,-,Q6,Q7,Q8][-,-,-,-,Q14,Q15,Q16][-,-,-,-,-,Q22,Q23,Q24][-,-,-,-,Q30,Q31,Q32]

When I connect wires on my breadboard to implement the LFSR with XOR feedback, I need taps 28 and 31, but 28 is not available.
QUESTIONS:

Do I need to select a different shift register IC that provides access to stages 28 and 31?

If I must use the CD4014B, will I have to select a different PRBS Test Pattern that uses the following potential tap points? [Q6,Q7,Q8,Q14,Q15,Q16,Q22,Q23,Q24,Q30,Q31,Q32]


Thank you for your interest and help!

Why are you using a parallel-input shift register? The 4015 is a dual 4-stage shift register that has a serial input and all outputs available. But if you're stuck with the 4014, just use a fifth one whose serial input is tied to O6 of the third one. This will give you bits 28, 29 and 30 at its outputs.

@DaveTweed Sounds like your comment is an answer to the questions then (which I read as "no" and "no").

Thanks Dave!  The description given to me included the 4014, but it was not a requirement.  Since the 4015 aligns better, I will build the prototype with it.  I have a lot of 4014s lying around, so I will give your other suggestion a whirl in case it is needed in the future.  Thanks again for your help!
